# Programmatically freezing/pausing rendering of widgets

Tags: flutter

I have a Stack widget with a bunch of positioned elements (Animated gifs, Webviews, ..).
These wigets can be edited, doing so opens a modal on-top of the current view, the Stack widget remains partially visible behind the modal, but I'd like to temporarily pause rendering of everything behind the modal until it's closed again.

I'm not looking for a way to remove these widgets entirely. Think of it as taking a screenshot of the current view and using that instead until the modal is closed again

Is there an accessible way to achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: what about `IndexedStack` and switching `index` between 0 and 1 where 0 means your `Stack` with a bunch of positioned elements and 1 means `Image` widget showing the freezed snapshot of the `Stack` (see `RepaintBoundary` on how to do that)

Comment: @pskink Unfortunately that would get tricky, since there is some webviews, and a lot of other widgets that I'd like to keep showing instead of replacing them. I think that the screenshot way (Screenshot the whole tree) is actually the best one in this case. I've just learned about TickerMode, and it worked for most elements but not the webviews, thank you!

Comment: "I think that the screenshot way" - this is exactly what i am talking about - you need to use `RepaintBoundary`, "convert" it to image (`RenderRepaintBoundary.toImage`) and show that image on `IndexedStack` - `IndexedStack(children: [Image, RepaintBoundary(child: Stack)])`

Comment: Yep, will do exactly that. Thank you so much!